# How to construct projection matrix with ortho-ish in y-axis and perspective in x-axis

Tags: 3d, shader, webgl

How would I create a matrix that maps coordinates like so:

Near plane

```
x: [-3,3] -> [-1,1]
y: [-6,2] -> [-1,1]
z: 2 -> -1
```

Far plane

```
x: [-4,4] -> [-1,1]
y: [-4,4] -> [-1,1]
z: 0 -> 1
```

[image: Illustration of frustum in xz-plane and yz-plane]

I can do it in the vertex shader with special function but would like to do it with a projection matrix, if possible.

```
vec4 special_projection(vec4 p){
  float ty = 0.25 * p.z;
  float tx = 0.25 * p.x;
  float xz = (tx / 3.0) * (p.z / 2.0);
  float x = tx + xz;
  float y = 0.25 * p.y + ty;
  float z = -0.5 * p.z;
  return vec4(x,y,z,1);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you desire is a not represantable with matrix multiplication in the 4d homogenous space you work in.

To get the perspective divide right, you would need to set `w_clip` to some linear  function of `z_eye`. Standard GL convention would be `w_clip = -z_eye`, and I'm going to use that here. To get `y` without the perspective distortion, you need to get `y_clip` multiplied by `w_clip = - z_eye`.

You can of course write whatever formula into the shader you like, but be warned that by distorting the space in the way you intend to do, the persepctive correction for the  interpolation  will yield results you might not expect.